# Mounting a directory of zipped files for direct unzipped access

Tags: mount, gzip, fuse, gvfs

I have a directory tree with LOTS of `.gz` files. I once saw a way to mount it (via FUSE I think) so that I could see all the files directly (i.e. unzipped) under another directory.

I've been searching for a while and it could have been `gvfs` but I don't see how to use it for that purpose; I did not see any examples besides `gvfsd-archive file.gz mountpoint` which is not what I'm looking for.

Read-only is fine for my purpose.

Comment: Could [this](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/virt-make-fs.1.html) be what you are looking for?  The whole concept will be slower than sin as it will need to unzip any file to look at it.

Comment: This look more like a file converter. I'm pretty sure I saw something where you could go to something like `~/.somecustomdir/root/user/dir/file.tgz/sub/content` and access the content file directly.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this sounds like the thing you may have used previously:

https://github.com/cybernoid/archivemount

ArchiveMount.

Looks easy to install:

```
Requirements
------------
You will need autoconf, libarchive-dev and libfuse-dev for building
archivemont, as well as GNU make and gcc of course.

Installation
------------
From version 0.6.0 on archivemount uses autoconf, so just do the normal

autoreconf -i
./configure && make && sudo make install

to build archivemount and install it to /usr/local. For building it,
libfuse is needed in version 2.6 or higher, including its headerfiles
of course (on most distributions those can be found in a package named
something like libfuse-dev or so).
```

And very simple to run:

```
Usage
-----
archivemount <options> <archive> <mountpoint>
Options are the normal fuse mount options, nothing special supported yet.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, `archivemount` can only mount a single archive file. I need one that can do it with LOTS of them.